# Custom exception with spring not thrown

Tags: java, spring, exception, nullpointerexception

I wrote a custom exception with Spring 5 reactive

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class AddressNotFoundException extends RuntimeException{
    public AddressNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
```

and I call this one in a service:

```
@Override
public Mono<Address> getById(String id) {
    Address addressFound=repository.findById(id).block();
    if(Objects.equals(addressFound, null))
        throw new AddressNotFoundException("Address #"+id+" not found");
    return Mono.just

(addressFound);
    }
```

but when I reach this page an exception is thrown but it's not a 404 but a null pointer exception and a error 500 page but with the correct message ?

The AddressNotFound is never thrown, only the Nullpointer exception but with my custom message ???
Can you help me please ?

Here is my controller :

```
  @GetMapping("/address/{id}")
    public Mono<Address> byId(@PathVariable String id) {
        return addressService.getById(id);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if your address is null,

repository.findById(id).block();

Should be throwing the NullPointerException I suppose. In that way it could never reach the code line to throw the custom exception.

Comment: I suppose but even with a simple route  public void error() throws AddressNotFoundException {
        throw ne it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending `RuntimeException` try extending just generic `Exception`.

Spring offers a `ControllerAdvice` annotation to intercept exceptions that are thrown

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
  @ExceptionHandler(value = { AddressNotFoundException.class })
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleAddressNotFoundException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    AddressNotFoundException notFound = (AddressNotFoundException)ex;
    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, String.valueOf(notFound), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, request);
  }
```

}

This will send the error back to the client as a 404 in which you can digest on the client side to display to the user typically in the form of a json string. Can either override the exceptions `toString` method to return it as a json or write a helper method that would do that.

Comment: still doesn't work :( There was an unexpected error (type=None, status=999).

Comment: Try adding another method in the `ExceptionController` to catch `NullPointerException` I think what Sudarshana Gurusinghe mentioned is happening where the `block()` call is throwing the null pointer since there is no object. Try getting rid of the `block()` call then test for null.

Comment: I've tried a simple throw new AddressNotFoundException() on another route and I have the same problem

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is change `@GetMapping` to `@RequestMapping` then add `'@ResponseBody` to the method as well so it would be `public @ResponseBody Mono<Address> byId(@PathVariable String id)`

Comment: I've tried but even on a clean project factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resour

Comment: Are you using `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in your xml or `@EnabledWebMvc` annotation. If you are using both that could cause the error. Also if the return object `Mono<Address>` can't be converted to json that might also cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a HandlerExceptionResolver bean which is causing 500 for some reason. Please try taking that off for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with spring boot 1.5 it works with Spring Boot 2 without webflux it works, so it seems that Webflux can't handle custom exception ???